# Reputation Tab on User Profile - Inconsistencies

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

When a question is up voted more than once, under the reputation tab of the user's profile we see the sum of the up votes with a drill down to the list when the question was up voted. I spotted a bit of an inconsistency there - as you can see, it says 2 events whereas, it lists all three up votes.

Once I refresh the page, it displays properly - 3 events and when you drill down, you see all three events.

It is not a bug as such - just an inconsistency!

[image]

Comment: @Raynold: Yes, as I said - once I refresh the page, it all appears fine.

Comment: may be it's a browser cache problem.